# Question about exterior derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, integration

I know from Carroll that the integration in GR is basically a mapping from n-form to the real number. And it's given that

$$d^nx=dx^0\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{n!}\epsilon_{\mu_1\ldots\mu_n}dx^{\mu_1}\ldots dx^{\mu_n}$$

Now, I have an expression that is given in spherical coordinate system, where I have

$$\int_\Sigma f(\theta,\phi) d\theta\wedge d\phi$$

when I want to integrate this (the epsilon part is already computed), do I just have $\int\int d\theta d\phi$ to integrate, or do I need to put the part from integration in spherical coordinate system $\int\int\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$?

I haven't done much integration that involved forms before, so any help is appreciated :)

EDIT:

From the article I have:

$$k_\xi[h,\bar{g}]=k^{[\nu\mu]}_\xi[h,\bar{g}](d^{n-2}x)_{\nu\mu}$$

$$(d^{n-p}x)_{\mu_1\ldots\mu_p}:=\frac{1}{p!(n-p)!}\epsilon_{\mu_1\ldots\mu_n}dx^{\mu_p+1}\ldots dx^{\mu_n}$$

$$k_\xi^{[\nu\mu]}[h,\bar{g}]=-\frac{\sqrt{-\bar{g}}}{16\pi}\ldots$$

where $\ldots$ is an expression.
Does this mean, since I have an $n-2$ form and I'm in 4 dimensional space, I need to include this $\sin\theta$ after all?

EDIT2: I need to add the $\sin\theta$. I got it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral you wrote down would simply be computed as follows:
\begin{align}
  \int_\Sigma f\,d\theta\wedge d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta f(\theta, \phi)
\end{align}
You just "erase the wedge."  The extra factor of $\sin\theta$ is included if you are integrating a 2-form $\omega$ that is proportional to the volume form;
\begin{align}
  \omega = f\,\epsilon
\end{align}
Here $\epsilon$ is the standard volume form on the sphere;
\begin{align}
  \epsilon = \sqrt{|\det(g_{ij})|}d\theta\wedge d\phi = \sin\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi, \qquad (g_{ij}) = \mathrm{diag}(1,\sin^2\theta)
\end{align}
So, for example, we would have
\begin{align}
  \int_\Sigma \omega = \int_\Sigma f\epsilon = \int_{\Sigma}f\sin\theta \,d\theta\wedge d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta \,\sin\theta f(\theta, \phi)
\end{align}

Comment: I will add an edit in my question, since equations won't end up good in comment :\

Comment: I need to add it, I got it after looking a bit :D Thanks :)